# Query to order on different tables doesn't work

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, dql

I have some entities/tables:

-Content
-ContentCategory
-Editor who can be premium and who create Contents
-Star (gold contents)like that: Star(IdContent, IdCategoryContent, IdEditor), because there can be only one star for each category for each editor.

I want a query to get every Contents but ordered to shows  only one content from each editor at first (star content of premium plan editors) and then every other contents.

What I tried, thanks for any help :

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('c')
    ->from('ContentBundle:Content', 'c')
    ->leftJoin('c.user', 'user')
    ->leftJoin('user.editoreditor', 'editor')
    ->leftJoin(
        'loic\ContentBundle\Entity\Star',
        'star',
        \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH,
        'c.idcontent = star.idContent'
    )
    ->orderBy('editor.plan', 'DESC')
    ->addOrderBy('star.idContent', 'DESC')
    ->addOrderBy('c.creationDate', 'DESC');
```

Comment: Can you please combined those queries into one, it is hard to read....

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql

Comment: @YunfeiChen I did, thank you.

Comment: @Strawberry you're right I tried, but without success

Comment: Well, if that's a road you think you might like to go down, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: From your description, it seems that the query nearly already does what you. I would suspect you would have to order `star.idContent` `ASC` so that non null values appear first, then contents with stars appear first. Otherwise maybe you want to know if the content has a star, therefor it makes sende to also select `star.id`. If `star.id` is set, the content has a star. Is that what you want?